# Does TileStache support serving vector MBTiles?

Tags: mbtiles, tilestache

Does TileStache support serving vector MBTiles?

I've looked at https://github.com/TileStache/TileStache/blob/master/TileStache/MBTiles.py , but I can't tell from this...

Comment: Still don't know about TileStache. `tileserver-gl-light` supports serving vector MBTiles -- see http://osm2vectortiles.org/docs/getting-started/ .

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. Here is an example tilestache.cfg file:

```json
{
  "index": "./index.html",
  "logging": "debug",
  "cache": {
    "name": "Disk",
    "path": "/tmp/tilestache",
    "umask": "0000"
  },
  "layers": {
    "default": {
      "provider": {
        "name": "mbtiles",
        "tileset": "./data/default.mbtiles",
         "maximum cache age": 604800
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See the tilestache documentation here: http://tilestache.org/doc/#mbtiles-provider